# Binary Search Python- by product list barcode

Tags: python, list, binary-search

i need to for binary search find a Product, we used a method to query the database using the product Barcode as the primary key value. but keeps giving me this error.

[binary search code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykydW.jpg)

[binary search being called looking for product list by barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epxGJ.jpg)

```
def binary_search(list_of_products):
bar_code = []
low = 0
high = len(list_of_products) - 1
mid = 0

while low <= high:

    mid = (high + low) // 2

    # If x is greater, ignore left half
    if (list_of_products[mid]).get_barcode() < bar_code:
        low = mid + 1

    # If x is smaller, ignore right half
    elif (list_of_products[mid]).get_barcode() > bar_code:
        high = mid - 1

    # means x is present at mid
    else:
        return mid

# If we reach here, then the element was not present
return -1
```

Comment: The `bar_code` is assigned wrong type, please try `bar_code = ""`.

Comment: i need to, find a Product, we used a method to query the database using the product Barcode as the primary key value. if that makes sense :) thanks heaps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code or errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you have an error to show, copy and paste the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, **as text**, formatted as you would format code. At any rate, I can't understand how the code is intended to work. Where the code says `(list_of_products[mid]).get_barcode() < bar_code`, for example, what do you expect to happen? Why? What do you expect is the value of `bar_code` at this point? Why?

Comment: Please also read [ask], and keep in mind that "can anyone help?" is [not a suitable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). If the question is "what does the error mean?", then please start by [trying to look things up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). If the question is "how do I fix the error?", then start by [thinking logically about what the program does and how the error is caused](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: no worries sorry ill be sure to not upload error images :)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing binary search value **(list_of_products[mid]).get_barcode()** and empty list **bar_code**

You need a target such as **target_product.get_barcode()** to be compared with (list_of_products[mid]).get_barcode().

```
def binary_search(list_of_products, target_product):
    bar_code = target_product.get_barcode()  # Need to define target
    low = 0
    high = len(list_of_products) - 1
    mid = 0
    
    while low <= high:
    
        mid = (high + low) // 2
    
        # If x is greater, ignore left half
        if (list_of_products[mid]).get_barcode() < bar_code:
            low = mid + 1
    
        # If x is smaller, ignore right half
        elif (list_of_products[mid]).get_barcode() > bar_code:
            high = mid - 1
    
        # means x is present at mid
        else:
            return mid
    
    # If we reach here, then the element was not present
    return -1

binary_search(list_of_products, target_product)  # add target_product when running
```

Comment: tried running this and it came up with error: 'target_product'

Comment: You should add a parameter primary key **target_product** when run **binary_search** function.

Comment: If you just want to compare with a **value** , not **product instance**, run like **binary_seach(list_of_prosucts, value)** and remove **.get_barcode()** function from **bar_code = target_product.get_barcode()** at above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the 'list of product' is a list of 'product' object sorted by its attribute 'barcode'. Since that is what you are going to compare. And all products have a barcode, that is no null value.

Now what you are actually do is searching the target value (your target product's barcode) on a sorted array (the list of barcode of your products.)

```
def binarySearch(list_of_product, bar_code): # bar_code is your target's barcode
    left = 0
    right = len(list_of_product) - 1

    while left <= right:
        mid = left + (right - left) // 2 # Avoid overflow

        if list_of_product[mid].get_barcode() == bar_code:
            return mid
        elif list_of_product[mid].get_barcode() < bar_code:
            left = mid + 1
        else: right = mid - 1
    
    return -1
```

Note the return value is the index of that specific product in the list. If the none of the product in the list contain that barcode, then the return value is -1.

There are also rooms for improvements. For example instead of passing a list of product objects, you could opt for passing just barcode as list, thus avoid multiple get_barcode() function call.